# Android SwipeRefreshLayout returns null

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I want to use a SwipeRefreshLayout for replace data,
but when i do

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
```

mSwipeRefreshLayout had null.
code example:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

  </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;


private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout ;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Toast.makeText(SpisokActivity.this, "Обновление", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
```

so, after
`mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.refresh)` i get an error. I think that the reason is mSwipeRefreshLayout  had null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this befor `findViewById`

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)
```

Comment: thank you. Error was because i write setContentView irregular layout.