# SwipeRefreshLayout setOnRefreshLayout Null Reference Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am using a fragment to run a webview and i want it to refresh when i swipe down but

swipeRefreshLayout return null when i run the app.

```
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link LiveFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class LiveFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    String url = "https://m.facebook.com/pages/category/Non-Governmental-Organization--NGO-/AfrikaMedia247-105319351628446/";
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public LiveFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LiveFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static LiveFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        LiveFragment fragment = new LiveFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtube, container, false);
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);
        webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewclient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        webView.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        webView.reload();
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }


    public class myWebViewclient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/lost.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
            handler.cancel();
        }





    }
}
```

This is the error it gives me when i run it:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference
```

I have tried the method from [Android SwipeRefreshLayout returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242338/android-swiperefreshlayout-returns-null) but it didnt work.

Comment: please check the id of your **swiperefreshlayout** in `fragment_youtube.xml`

Comment: i have checked it

Comment: To make sure it is only this line causing the NPE, try removing that line. If the refresh layout still throws an NPE, then the id is incorrect or doesnt exist in fragment_youtube.

Comment: i did remove the line